# Better way convert json to SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

These days I am learning SQLAlchemy. When I want to load an object from json and save it to MySQL, things get difficult because the fields in my model are more that 20 and I wonder whether there're better ways to do this.

My original code follows as an example:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

json_str = """{"id": 1, "name": "yetship"}"""
obj = json.loads(json_str)
user = User(id=obj.get("id"), name=obj.get("name"))
```

It can work but as I add more fields, it gets awful.

Comment: Why not use a database that natively supports json documents?

Comment: it's only a dump and load feature, no need for this and use nosql dbs...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have in your json file only fields that you can initialize your `User` from. Then you simply can do.

```
user = User(**obj)
```

`**obj` will unpack your `dict` object, so if have `obj = {'id': 1, 'name': 'Awesome'}`, `User(**obj)` will do like `User(id=1, name='Awesome')`

You can see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

NOTE: it's better to avoid using `id` as a variable|field, because `'id' in dir(__builtin__)`, so `id` in bultins

**UPD**

If you have in your json fields that don't belong to that model you can filter them out with dict comprehension

```
user = User(**{k:v for k, v in obj.items() if k in {'id', 'name'}})
```

**UPD for UPD**

It depends on the size of you `obj`, in most of the cases it's probably better (*performance and clarity*) to iterate over `('id', 'name')` rather than `obj.items()`:

```
user = User(**{k: obj[k] for k in ('id', 'name') if k in obj})
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by avoiding using `id`? The way it is currently written does not make sense.

Comment: @deed02392 i mean `id` is builtin keyword, so if you redeclare it, you won't be able to use function `id()`. Also IDEs highlight them accordingly.